# How can I render each output as they calculate instead of rendering them all at once?

Tags: shiny

I have an app with several outputs. I'd like each output to render as it calculates rather than waiting for all of the other calculations. Please see below for a reproducible example. My desired behavior is for distPlot to render before distPlot_2 rather than at the same time.

```
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot"),
           plotOutput("distPlot_2"),
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
    
    output$distPlot_2 <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2]
      
      Sys.sleep(3)
      
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
      
      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You'll need [intra-session async futures](https://github.com/rstudio/promises/issues/23#issuecomment-386687705) to realize the desired behaviour.